# Error 550 Mail Relay Message Could Not Be Sent

Tags: email-server

I'm not sure if this is the right area to ask, but here we go. I have a client who has a couple websites on a Windows server with MailEnable as the mail manager. Any emails being sent from the server work great, except when sending to some domains, the message does not go through due to the following error:

```
12/13/11 01:15:56   ME-I0026: [86476200E5834227A819E6E63E0EFDA2.MAI] Sending message 
12/13/11 01:15:57   ME-IXXXX: [86476200E5834227A819E6E63E0EFDA2.MAI] Remote server returned a response indicating a permanent error. Server Response: (550 Relaying not allowed**)
12/13/11 01:15:57   ME-E0036: [86476200E5834227A819E6E63E0EFDA2.MAI] MAIL FROM command Failed.
```

Can anyone give me some leads on how to correct the settings to allow emails to go through properly? In particular, the emails are not going through to a Network Solutions email account and Network Solutions has not been very helpful thus far.

In addition, can a domain's DNS settings affect this error? Currently, the domains are hosted by Network Solutions and use the Network Solutions email service to send/receive email. The server is located with a different company and the Domains' DNS points to it. Which mail related DNS entries are allowed or not allowed in this scenario?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`550 Relaying not allowed` error on final recipient (?) side means obvious things

- It's misconfigured MTA on foreign side (accepted mail **must be re-sent** to some another host, but **relaying is prohibited**) - mostly it's because host was *defined as MX* in zone, but domain *not added as served* in MTA... but other reasons also possible
- You can do nothing from the emitter's MTA side
- DNS-settings of sender's domain aren't related in any form with this problem
- If you want to help in troubleshooting, you can suggest to write (or write) e-mail to postmaster@ with description of problem with **as much technical details, as possible**, i.e. smth. like

> Dear postmaster of host ...!
>
> On sending e-mail from  at  from user  to
>   user  of domain , served by your MTA as
>   (primary|backup) MX, 550 error 'Relaying not allowed' happened. This
>   error was repeated also for (the same sender-recipient pair|such
>   sender-recipient pairs as ...) at  N times total.
>
> Please help us to eliminate this trouble

PS: You can also name (some of) recipient's domains here or privately, I'll (*maybe*) see at MTAs behavior

Comment: Pardon for asking, what is "MTA"? By foreign side, do you mean the mail host? (it's Network Solutions)

Comment: MTA is "Message Transport Agent" - program, which perform e-mail delivery between hops. "Foreign" side is host, which must accept mail, emitted from your MTA

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with my MailEnable server. The Primary DNS server was not able to resolve the target domain's IP address correctly. I flushed the DNS entries and register them again. It worked for me. Hope it will help someone.